# python slice a string and use .find to get last three letters to determine the type of file

Tags: python, find, slice

what i am asking is how can i correct my if statement, essentially i have a file attachment called 'fileName' and i am trying to get the last 3 letters from that file to determine if that type of file is in my config (csv, txt).

valid_filename = myconfig file (csv, txt)

```
def load_file():
    try:
        # get file from read email and assign a directory path (attachments/file)
        for fileName in os.listdir(config['files']['folder_path']):
            # validate the file extension per config
            # if valid_filename:  else send email failure
            valid_filename = config['valid_files']['valid']
            if fileName[-3:].find(valid_filename):
                file_path = os.path.join(config['files']['folder_path'], fileName)
                # open file path and read it as csv file using csv.reader
                with open(file_path, "r") as csv_file:
                    csvReader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
                    first_row = True
```

let me know if i can clarify anything better

Comment: you should use `pathlib.Path` to handle paths, then you can just check `my_path.suffix`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try pathlib, for example

Assuming the config file is in the form:

```
[valid_files]
valid = .csv, .txt
[files]
forder_path = .
```

```
# other imports
import pathlib

def load_file():
    valid_suffixes = [e.strip() for e in config['valid_files']['valid'].split(",")]
    folder_path = config['files']['folder_path']
    for fileName in os.listdir(folder_path):
        if pathlib.Path(filename).suffix in valid_suffixes:
            file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, fileName)
            with open(file_path, "r") as csv_file:
                ...
```

Comment: if Path(fileName).suffix == config['valid_files']['valid']:
so would this work assuming i have more than one type of file in my config?

Comment: @python_noob :  See in my completed example. Yes you can text for more the a single suffix type

Comment: thank you so much that is very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

`find()` method returns `-1` if the string you're searching for is not found. To check if the element exists in the string, check if `find` returns `-1`.

Comment: right would it look something like this?

Comment: if fileName[-3:].find(valid_filename) >= 0:

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: it isn't working and i don't know why cause that seems correct :/

Comment: Are you getting an exception?

Comment: I'd suggest you follow hpchavaz's reply.

Comment: i did! i got it working using path, however i am going to try to figure out why this method didn't work as it should be. thank you for the help as well!